# Why does my JS object incorrectly change when not assigning the object to a variable?

Tags: javascript, linked-list, javascript-objects

Please explain this phenomenon to me.

```js
this.testObject = { a: 1, b: { a: 3, b: { a: 78, b: null } } };

let g = this.testObject;

while (g.b) {
  g = g.b;
}

g.b = {
  a: 79,
  b: null
};

console.log(this.testObject); // { a: 1, b: { a: 3, b: { a: 78, b: { a: 79, b: null } } } }
```

Now I decided to stick with `this.testObject` and removed `g`:

```js
this.testObject = { a: 1, b: { a: 3, b: { a: 78, b: null } } };

while (this.testObject.b) {
  this.testObject = this.testObject.b;
}

this.testObject.b = {
  a: 79,
  b: null
};
console.log(this.testObject); // {a": 78,b": {a": 79,b": null}
```

What’s going on? How is my assignment of `g` affecting this object this way?

In first snippet, if I did `g=g.b` then I am basically assigning a new value to `g`. However if I explicitly do this, then result isn't same?

```js
this.testObject = {a:1, b:{a:3,b:{a:78, b:null}}};
let g = this.testObject;

while(g.b){
    g = {a:7777, b:null};
}

g.b={a:79, b:null};
this.testObject; // {a": 1,b": {a": 3,b": {a": 78,b": null}
```

Comment: ?? Your loop clearly *changes* `this.testObject` to a series of new values. Nothing changes it back to its original value.

Comment: What is the expected bevhavior?

Comment: Yes but I did the same when i wrote `let g = this.testObject;` How come it is accepting phenomena at line 6 in first phase differently compared to line 5 in phase 2?

Comment: `g` and `this.testObject` are two separate modifiable things (`g` is a variable and `this.testObject` is an object property).  Changing `g` does **not** change the value of `this.testObject`.

Comment: Oh so javascript is using the very fact that object's property of being mutable and g is just a shallow copy here?

Comment: @TrickOrTreat `g` is _not_ a copy. It’s just a reference. Reassigning `g` does not affect the previously assigned reference.

Comment: See [Variable re-assignment of object reference leaves other object unaltered (no “transitive” assignment)](/q/41814414/4642212).

Comment: But why `g = {a:7777, b:null};` is working different (as it's not considering `g.b={a:79, b:null};` ) but `g=g.b` . is able to include `g.b={a:79, b:null};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when answering these question people draw boxes and arrows between them to indicate pointers, but I'm lazy, so let's consider a simple virtual machine instead. This machine can operate on memory blocks and their numbers (aka "pointers"). There are three operations:

- allocate: allocate a memory block, initialize it with some data and return a pointer to it (denoted `$number`)
- write: set the value of a variable or a property to a pointer, so that the variable "points" to the corresponding memory block
- read: given a pointer, return the content of its memory block

In terms of this machine, your first snippet would translate to this:

```
// this.testObject = { a: 1, b: { a: 3, b: { a: 78, b: null } } };

allocate: $1 = {a: 78, b: null}
allocate: $2 = {a: 3, b: $1}
allocate: $3 = {a: 1, b: $2}

write: this.testObject = $3

// let g = this.testObject;

write: g = $3

// while (g.b) {  g = g.b; }

write: g = $3.b // first pass, g is now $2
write: g = $2.b // second pass, g is now $1

// g.b = { a: 79, b: null }

allocate: $4 = { a: 79, b: null }

write: $1.b = $4

// console.log(this.testObject);

read: $3 ==> {a: 1, b: $2}
read: $2 ==> {a: 3, b: $1}
read: $1 ==> {a: 78, b: $4}
read: $4 ==> { a: 79, b: null }
```

Basically, each `{...}` is an "allocate" operation, each assignment is a "write" and `console.logs` are "reads". Try to "translate" your other snippets to this machine and you'll see what's actually going on.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're expecting the two snippets to produce the same result. But the code doesn't do the same thing.

You're using `g` as a sort of reference in the first example. This means that every time you set `g` in the while loop, you're not affecting `this.testObject` in any way since you're just "moving" the reference. But it is still a reference, so altering anything inside the object that `g` is referencing, you will also set it in `this.testObject`, thus producing the result you get in the first example.

In the second example, you're replacing `this.testObject` each time in the while loop. So setting `this.testObject = this.testObject.b` will remove the outer object, resulting in `this.testObject` going from:

```
{ a: 1, b: { a: 3, b: { a: 78, b: null } } }
```

To:

```
{ a: 3, b: { a: 78, b: null } }
```

And since `this.testObject.b` isn't null, you're repeating this again, making `this.testObject` become:

```
{ a: 78, b: null }
```

Lastly, you're setting `this.testObject.b` to a new object, overwriting the previous null value. This results in the output you get in the second example.

Comment: I just updated my fears in javascript code back again. Please have a look.

Comment: But why `g = {a:7777, b:null};` is working different (as it's not considering `g.b={a:79, b:null};` ) but `g=g.b` . is able to include `g.b={a:79, b:null};`

Comment: @TrickOrTreat Every time you write `g = ...`, you're reassigning what `g` is referencing to. With your new code example, you're first assigning `g` to point at `this.testObject`, but then you overwrite that reference with the new `{a:7777, b:null};`. Since you're moving the referencing, you're not altering `this.testObject` in any way. I'd suggest looking at [this article](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0), which explains the difference between values and references in javascript.

Comment: oh.ok. Thanks for this explaining. This helps.